# Split Integers Using Stream Lambda

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-stream

I was studying usage of Stream and Lambda in Java8. How would you go about applying Stream and Lambda for the following: Print out the odd integers in the following string: "[3, 6, 8, 96, 7, 23]" using Stream and Lambda.

I figured out it was pretty simple using a for loop and parseInt but how would one implement streams and lambda.

Comment: Show us what you have done first?

Comment: I don't have the code with me at the moment, but one can split everything based on the commas, then push each element into an array, then perhaps remove the brackets from the first and last element then take the remainder and print it if its mod 2 value is 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use substring with split like so :

```
String str = "[3, 6, 8, 96, 7, 23]";
Arrays.stream(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(", "))
        .filter(s -> Integer.valueOf(s) % 2 != 0)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you want to get an array, then you can use [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) like so :

```
.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or if you want to get an array of Integers, you can use a map then a filter like so :

```
Integer[] array = Arrays.stream(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(", "))
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

**Outputs**

```
3
7
23
```

Comment: Awesome thanks...just to clarify - what is the benefit of stream and lambda vs simpler approaches form Java 7

Comment: I can't gives you a full answer about that question, for that I invite you to lean in details https://dzone.com/articles/why-java-8-1, and many other books and forums in internet

Answer (score 1):

Converting String to String[] by splitting it by "[", "]", " ", and ","
then filtering blank values and not odd integers

```
Arrays.stream("[3, 6, 8, 96, 7, 23]".split("[,\\s\\[\\]]"))
.filter(s->!s.isBlank() && Integer.valueOf(s)%2!=0)
.forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
```